Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub, "bad credentials"
I'm having problems with installing the package gpinter. When I try to install it by:
remotes::install_github("thomasblanchet/gpinter")
The following error appears:
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 27/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2021-09-30 19:17:49 UTC

Same error if I use devtools instead of remotes, if I run Sys.unsetenv("GITHUB_PAT") before, or, if add auth_token = NULL in install_github, as suggested in related questions here and there.

So what is the exact output of remotes::install_github("thomasblanchet/gpinter", auth_token=NULL)? Does it still say "Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT"? What version of remotes do you have installed?

Erreur : Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 59/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2024-07-18 15:34:47 UTC

remotes version 2.4.2.1

What is the output of usethis::git_sitrep()?

It's too long to post here. It summarizes my github credentials. It says: ✖ Can't get user information for this token.
The token may no longer be valid or perhaps it lacks the 'user' scope.
Error in gh():
It also says ✖ The 'origin' remote is configured, but we can't determine its default branch.

So it's finding a token somewhere. Maybe see the guidance on https://usethis.r-lib.org/articles/git-credentials.html on how to remove it or change it. It's not clear how you would have set it up in the first place. Maybe try gitcreds::gitcreds_delete(url = "https://github.com")

Your suggestion doesn't work. I noticed that I had defined the path in .Renviron. Now I have removed this line, tried to restart R, and R doesn't start anymore: "R encountered a fatal error. The session is terminated."

Is there anything in your .Renviron file now? What path did you define exactly? If that's all you changed that shouldn't stop R for working. If you rename the file, R should be able to start without that file.
